# unable to insert row at id, but row does not exist

Tags: postgresql, insert, primary-key

Here is the weird problem i am facing. I am trying to enter data using following query

```
insert into product_product 
(id, product_tmpl_id, make_equip, model_equip, name_template, serial_num_equip, location_equip, issue_date_equip, issue_to_equip, remarks_equip, pr, ch,  categ_id,valuation) 
values (700,700,'Nikon','Action 10x50 Lookout','Nikon Action 10x50 Lookout','671386','40 Wall St.','5/13/2004 12:00:00 AM','','OM''s OFFICE',62,72,502,'manual periodic');
```

I get the error :

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_product_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(700) already exists.

********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "product_product_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (id)=(700) already exists.
```

I ran select query on that record like this:

```
select * from product_product
where id=700
```

It returns columns with no data(data includes id too)

I tried to run update query like this:

```
update product_product set 
                        product_tmpl_id=700,
                        make_equip='Nikon', 
                        model_equip='Action 10x50 Lookout', 
                        name_template='Nikon Action 10x50 Lookout', 
                        serial_num_equip='671386', 
                        location_equip='40 Wall St.', 
                        issue_date_equip='5/13/2004 12:00:00 AM', 
                        issue_to_equip='',
                        remarks_equip='OM''s OFFICE', 
                        pr=62, 
                        ch=72, 
                        categ_id=502,valuation='manual periodic' where id=700;
```

result was:

```
Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 1 ms execution time.
```

i tried delete query too but same output.

Also show all data shows nothing like id 700.

I don't know why this is happening.

I re indexed and Vacuumed my table from maintenance but same result.

Plz let me know what is wrong with it.

Thanks

**Edit**

here is my create table

```
CREATE TABLE product_product
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  create_uid integer,
  create_date timestamp without time zone,
  write_date timestamp without time zone,
  write_uid integer,
  ean13 character varying(13), -- EAN13 Barcode
  color integer, -- Color Index
  image bytea, -- Image
  price_extra numeric, -- Variant Price Extra
  default_code character varying(64), -- Internal Reference
  name_template character varying(128), -- Template Name
  .....
  description_sale text,
  procure_method character varying,
  produce_delay double precision,
  uom_id integer,
  name character varying,
  office_equip character varying, -- Office(Equipment)
  lease_agreement_equip character varying, -- Lease Agreement
  reg_exp_date_equip character varying, -- Registration Expiration Date
  CONSTRAINT product_product_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT product_product_categ_temp2_fkey FOREIGN KEY (categ_temp2)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_categ_temp3_fkey FOREIGN KEY (categ_temp3)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_categ_temps_fkey FOREIGN KEY (categ_temps)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_categg_temp_fkey FOREIGN KEY (categg_temp)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_ch_fkey FOREIGN KEY (ch)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_create_uid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (create_uid)
      REFERENCES res_users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_my_products_fkey FOREIGN KEY (my_products)
      REFERENCES product_product (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_phone_data_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (phone_data_id)
      REFERENCES phone_datas (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_phone_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (phone_id)
      REFERENCES phone_types (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_pr_fkey FOREIGN KEY (pr)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_product_tmpl_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_tmpl_id)
      REFERENCES product_template (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_subchild_fkey FOREIGN KEY (subchild)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_temp_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (temp_id)
      REFERENCES product_category (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT product_product_write_uid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (write_uid)
      REFERENCES res_users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I have something like 200+ columns, so i have removed them from here....

Image of last rows in product_product is [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column **id** is defined as **SERIAL** which is similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases.
So you should omit it in the **INSERT** statement or use the DEFAULT keyword and the new **id** will be generated automatically.

See section 8.1.4. Serial Types: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html